# update then replace dies

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If there is a row for user_id then I want to update, if not insert (but I was told to use replace). In the table there is id (which is primary key, auto inc) and user_id (index, session relates to). I have a form that when the data is changed it should be changed in the database for that particular user in session, otherwise it is just added for that particular user in session

```
if (empty($err)) {

        $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name']);
        $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);



$query="UPDATE thesis SET thesis_Name ='$thesis_Name',
abstract='$abstract' WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'
IF ROW_COUNT()=0
REPLACE INTO  thesis (thesis_Name,abstract)VALUES ('$thesis_Name', '$abstract')
";

mysql_query($query) or die();

 // query is ok?
 if (mysql_query($the_query, $link) ){

 // redirect to user profile
 header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);
        }
```

With this the page just dies.

EDIT:

```
`thesis` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`thesis_Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`abstract` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
 )
```

Thanks so much

Comment: You **really** should use prepared statements!  If you don't know how, or why, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @eggyal: `php::mysql` does not support them. `$_SESSION` is not user-provided, the other variables are escaped.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Fair point... although it still makes me shudder.

Comment: @Quassnoi I'd suggest you look into PDO instead of using the nearly-outdated php::mysql.  Or at a minimum, use mysqli.  Prepared statements are VASTLY less likely to run into various nasty injection assaults, some of which can escape even a thorough sanitization effort.  (Quarantine completely bypasses the need to sanitize, making it IMPOSSIBLE to inject)

Comment: @RonLugge: I'm not the @op. `php::mysql` may be used for a reason:  some hosters do not provide anything but `php::mysql`; there are extendable applications built on `php::mysql` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT
INTO    thesis (id, abstract, thesis)
VALUES  ('$_SESSION[user_id]', '$abstract', '$thesis_Name')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
        abstract = VALUES(abstract),
        thesis_Name = VALUES(thesis_Name)
```

Comment: I get red lines everywhere with this? Ive put a bracket on the end of values

Comment: will it have anything to do with that I am echoing the field?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the `UPDATE` first - `REPLACE` handles all of this for you.  From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See [Section 13.2.5, “`INSERT` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html).

Therefore, so long as `id` is a unique key in your `thesis` table, the only SQL you need is:

```
REPLACE INTO thesis (id, thesis_Name, abstract)
VALUES ('$_SESSION[userid]', '$thesis_name', '$abstract');
```

Comment: `REPLACE` is outdated and less efficient than `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. On a key hit, it's a `DELETE` followed by `INSERT` (2 operations) vs. an `UPDATE` (1 operation or even a no-op if the updated values match old ones).

Comment: @user1296762: Where are you pasting it?  Where are you seeing 'red lines'?  I have no idea to what you're referring.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Agreed, but I was trying to keep as close to the OP's knowledge/original query as possible.

Comment: @user1296762: "red line errors" is not descriptive. Please post the error message from your web server logs.

Comment: Sorry I am putting it under `$abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);` as seen in question. the red lines in the program I'm using meaning syntax errors

Comment: @user1296762: The code goes between the `"` marks that demark the string being assigned to `$query`; thus you should have `$query = "REPLACE ...";`

Comment: Thats what I thought. I tried this and although it sent me back to me location, the data did not change. I will put my table structure in my question to see if that helps

Comment: @user1296762: Do you have a unique/primary key defined on the `id` column?

Comment: yes id is the primary key. i've put table structure into my answer

Comment: will it have anything to do with that I am echoing the field?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with prepared statements.You can see an example sql ;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `UPDATETHESIS`

|

CREATE PROCEDURE `UPDATETHESIS` (IN _id VARCHAR(50), IN _thesis_name VARCHAR(50), IN _abstract VARCHAR(50))

    NOT DETERMINISTIC

    CONTAINS SQL

    SQL SECURITY INVOKER

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM thesis WHERE id = _id)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE thesis SET thesis_Name = _thesis_name,
        abstract = _abstract WHERE id = _id    
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO thesis (thesis_Name,abstract) VALUES (_thesis_name, _abstract)
    END
```

You can call this like `CALL UPDATETHESIS(userid, thesis_name, abstratc);`

Comment: The question is tagged `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code that pose problem. First you don't have to do an insert and a replace in the same query : replace will insert if there is no row to replace (besides, I'm not even sure the sql syntax you're using is correct)...

Then you do a `mysql_query($query) or die()` which is probably where your code dies (maybe due to the fact that the sql syntax you used could be incorrect).

Right after that, you do a mysql_query again, which would reexecute the query a second time. Anyway, if your query didn't work, your code would have died on the previous line...

What you could do would be

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO blablabla";
if (!mysql_query($query))
echo "the query failed";
else header ("location:blabla");
```

but your query should mention for which user_id you want to update like this
REPLACE INTO thesis (id, thesis_Name, abstract)
VALUES ('{$_SESSION[userid]}', '$thesis_name', '$abstract');

Comment: I had to get rid of {} round session or it was giving errors. data still doesnt change in database though